# Eigenfunctions of squared angular momentum from differential equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

In spherical coordinates, the eigenfunctions of the operator $\hat{L}^2$ can be obtained by solving the problem
$$
-\dfrac{\hbar^2}{\sin\theta}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left(\sin\theta\dfrac{\partial Y(\theta,\varphi)}{\partial\theta}\right) - \dfrac{\hbar^2}{\sin^2\theta}\dfrac{\partial^2 Y(\theta,\varphi)}{\partial\varphi^2} = \lambda Y(\theta,\varphi) \ .
$$
I want to solve this directly without using extra information, such as the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the operator $\hat{L}_z$.

Using separation of variables, $Y(\theta,\varphi) = \Theta(\theta)\Phi(\varphi)$, I can separate the partial differential equation in two problems by using a separation constant $\mu$:
$$
-\dfrac{\hbar^2\sin\theta}{\Theta}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left(\sin\theta\dfrac{\partial \Theta}{\partial\theta}\right) - \lambda\sin^2\theta = \dfrac{\hbar^2}{\Phi}\dfrac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial\varphi^2} = -\mu
$$

I know that the problem regarding $\Theta(\theta)$ can be reduced to an equation whose solutions are the associated Legendre polynomials if $\lambda = l(l+1)\hbar^2$, so there is no problem with that. My problem is when solving the equation for $\Phi(\varphi)$, which can be written as
$$
\dfrac{\partial^2\Phi}{\partial\varphi^2} = -\dfrac{\mu}{\hbar^2}\Phi = -m^2\Phi\ ,\quad\mu = m^2\hbar^2\ .
$$
The general solution to this equation is
$$
\Phi(\varphi) = Ae^{im\varphi} + Be^{-im\varphi}\ ,
$$
but I know from the eigenfunctions of $\hat{L}_z$ that it should be reduced to just $\Phi(\varphi) = Ae^{im\varphi}$, and that the official solutions for the eigenfunctions of $\hat{L}^2$ are $$Y_{l,m}(\theta,\varphi) = \Theta_{l,m}(\theta)\Phi_m(\varphi)\propto P_{l,m}(\cos\theta)e^{im\varphi}\ .$$
Applying the periodicity condition to the angle $\varphi$, I have that
$$
\Phi(0) = \Phi(2\pi) \ \Rightarrow\ A + B = Ae^{i2\pi m} + Be^{-i2\pi m}\ ,
$$
which, as far as I know, it only tells me that $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. So, ¿how can I get $B = 0$ to fulfill with the official solution?

Comment: Just think about the solution and what it physically means. Then you'll see that the two solutions simply provide you with the ability to specify a solution with an arbitrary phase. In other words you don't need to expect that $B=0$.

Comment: @flippiefanus Ok so, rewriting the solution with an arbitrary phase, I guess that just dropping that phase is fine, since two quantum states are equivalent if they differ only by a global phase factor. Is that what you mean?

Comment: There is no requirement that $m >0$

Comment: As soon as you know that $m \in Z$, the part including  $B$ is redundant...

Comment: Yes, in the context of a state in QM, you can ignore the global phase.